# Number with given digit distribution multiplied by rational

Tags: number-theory

Let $x$ be an irrational number whose base-$m$ expansion has each digit $i$ (for $0 \leq i \leq m-1$) appearing with average frequency tending to $p_i>0$ (and $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} p_i=1$).

If $q \neq 0$ is rational, are there any known results regarding the distribution of the digits in $q \cdot x$? In the simplest case, when $q = m^{k}$ (for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), the distribution is of course unchanged.

I'm aware that if $x$ is normal in base $m$ (i.e. the average frequency of any finite digit sequence $i_1 i_2  \ldots i_k$ tends to $m^{-k}$), then $q \cdot x$ is normal in base $m$ as well, for any rational $q \neq 0$.

Comment: I doubt the last statement. Let $x=0.01010101\ldots$ has $p_i=\frac12$ (with $m=2$), but $3x$ is not normal.

Comment: You are correct. My definition of normal numbers was incomplete... I've edited it now.